# How to convert text to date (YYYY-MM-DD format) in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, time

So i have a table named 'employe' with the column 'employee_hire_date' (type text, DD-MM-YYYY format) and i want to format all the data to date type, or at least change the format with an update to make it YYYY-MM-DD, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a fixed-width format, you can use [`substr`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) to get all the pieces and then reassemble them by [concatenating them with `||`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#operators_and_parse_affecting_attributes).

```
-- DD-MM-YYYY -> YYYY-MM-DD
update employees
set employee_hire_date =
  -- YYYY
  substr(employee_hire_date, 7, 4) || '-' ||
  -- MM
  substr(employee_hire_date, 4, 2) || '-' ||
  -- DD
  substr(employee_hire_date, 1, 2);
```

[The datatype of the column does not matter](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values
>
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
>
> Applications can choose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions.

Comment: I tried that and one of the results is:

employee_hire_date

2-15-8--20

Comment: @Bluzk Check the formatting of your dates. Is it 4-5-2020 or 04-05-2020? The second is fixed-width `DD-MM-YYYY`, the first is not.

Comment: I got it now, thank you!!!